# Manage system parameter with type in web application

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, spring-mvc

In short, I want to know if there is a way to make a parameter class & validate them by annotation.

A typical parameter table should be:

TABLE

| id | param_name | param_value |

```
class Parameter {
  int id;
  String paramName;
  String paramValue;
  // ...
}
```

But with this typical way, I must make param_value as String (for universal purpose). Monthly money, subscription period, company address... all is the same type: string.

It's fairly ok, but I want to use Spring Annotation Validation to the parameters. If I consider all param_value as string pairs, I would not be able to validate them by annotation(`@Min(0) int monthlyMoney`, for example). That means I must validate them all by hand, which is not elegant.

Another reason for which I don't like this solution, is that I already know for sure that a monthlyMoney parameter must be an int; but still declare them as a string. It's counter-intuitive.

Also, I can make 'static' parameter into a table, like:

```
class ParameterNew {
  int id;
  int monthlyMoney;
  String companyAddress;
}
```

By that way, I can easily validate them by annotation. But this approach has a drawback: I'm currently using Hibernate, and it will take a whole table to store ONLY 1 TUBE.

Does Spring support any thing for this kind of parameter management?

Comment: whats wroing with a table with only 1 record if thats what you need? It's often needed to have database global values and you are better of with one row instead of stringly typed parameters

Comment: @Firo: I feel it too, but I think it should be another more elegant way.

Comment: there is another approach for seldom changing data http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/08/from-db-to-ram-wellknowinstancetype.html. you can even load it from somewhere else

Comment: @Firo: yes. I thought about loading from properties file, but in that case, it would be a string... In fact, the value that I'm trying to manage here is changeable by user.

Comment: i still se no real other option than to have the one row table